# Объясните алгоритм заполнения массива двойной спиралью во внутрь и изнутри. Так же как ниже

Tags: c++, матрицы

```
0 1 2 3 4
15 18 19 24 5
14 17 20 23 6
13 16 21 22 7
12 11 10 9 8
```

Написал прогу на одну спираль , на втроую не выходит

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

    // расширение функционала iostream,
                        // в частности setw()
        using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int const n=5;
    int const m=5;

int Arr[n][m]= {0};
int i=0, j, k = 0, p=1;

while (i < n*m) /*Цикл по номеру витка*/
 {
    k++;
    for (j=k-1;j<m-k+1;j++)
    {
        Arr[k-1][j]=p++;
        i++;
    }   /*Определение значений верхнего гор столбца*/ 
    for (j=k;j<n-k+1;j++)
    {
        Arr[j][m-k]=p++;
        i++;
    }   /* --//-- По правому вертикальному столбцу*/

    for (j=m-k-1;j>=k-1;j--)
    {
        Arr[n-k][j]=p++;
        i++;
    }   /* --//-- по нижнему горизонтальному столбцу*/ 

    for (j=n-k-1;j>=k;j--)
    {
        Arr[j][k-1]=p++;
        i++;
    }   /* --//-- по левому вертикальному столбцу*/

 }

for (int q=0; q<n; q++)
{
    for (int w=0; w<m; w++)
    { 
        cout << setw(4) << Arr[q][w];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
return(0);

}
```

Comment: Мне кажется что между 15 и 16 у вас "разрыв". Не вижу "двойной спирали"

Comment: У вас код дико сложный, эти спирали можно рисовать по принципу змейки - передвигаем курсор в одну сторону, заполняя поле, пока не упремся в границы массива или в заполненное поле, затем поворачиваем на 90 градусов. Двойная спираль рисуется поочередным перемещением двух таких курсоров.